# BufferedReader doesn't read from tcp server

Tags: java, android, tcp, bufferedreader

So I have this really strange bug in my android app. I'm trying to connect to a TCP server, and trade some messages, nothing complex, really. I've managed to surpass all the problems it had in the beginning, but now I'm stuck on a bug for which I hope someone knows how to fix.

I connect to the server and get the input and output stream successfully, but then, when reading the response from the server, the program freezes. I've researched this and I know that it's because there's no message from the server. But I also know that the server responds, since I've made the same app for iOS and it received everything alright. Can it be some android problem? or maybe just some setting in the system?

Here's a snippet of the code, showing you that this isn't a big deal. I don't much more stuff in the code, but if you need to look at the rest of it please ask.

Thanks in advance!

```
try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);

            tcpSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
            Log.e("socket",
                    "created socket with " + serverIP
                            + Integer.toString(serverPort));

            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(tcpSocket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            Log.e("socket", "output stream created alright");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tcpSocket.getInputStream()));
            Log.e("socket", "input stream created alright");
            out.println("handheld#" + clientID + "#connection request");
            fromServer = in.read();
            while(fromServer != -1) {
                fromServer = in.read(); //updated, still no good
            }


            connected = true;
            Log.e("socket", "connect thread will finnish");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("socket", "error finding host", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("socket", "error creating socket's streams", e);
        }
```

Comment: It freezes in the first in.read();

Comment: Of course it does. It should be.. while (fromServer != -1) fromServer = in.read();

Comment: yup that's true, thanks. but tried that now that's corrected and it still doesn't move...

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code work fine

```
    InputStream in = tcpSocket.getInputStream();
    if(in == null)
     return null;
    Log.e("socket", "input stream created alright");
    out.println("handheld#" + "1111" + "#connection request");


    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];

    int read = -1;
    long totalRead = 0;
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) 
   {
    out.write(buff, 0, read);
    Log.i("readed Byte ", new String(buff));

    totalRead += read;
    if (totalRead % 100 * 1024 == 0) 
    { 
      System.out.printf("%d bytes read\n", totalRead); 
   }
  }
```

i have implemented in my sample which read successfully from inputstream.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, really. I understand the problems you are trying to prevent and the optimizations you are doing. But do you think it will help me? Do you think it's something in my code? (I didn't try this yet, though)

Comment: I tried, still the same problem. I really think it has something to do with android on my device or something. what else can it be? the code's right, the server responds..